# Volatile for reference type - Does it always avoid publication of references issues due to JMM?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety, volatile

Assuming this class:

```
public class AmIThreadSafe {

    private int a;
    private int b;

    AmIThreadSafe(int a, int b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }
}
```

Assuming that instance's reference to this class (declared as `volatile`) is accessible by some threads (leading to race condition) as soon as the `this`(reference) escapes:

```
volatile AmIThreadSafe instance = new AmIThreadSafe(1,2);
```

Here, I'm sure that the fact of assigning `instance` reference *happens-before* reading by threads.

But what about the `AmIThreadSafe's` fields?

Does the external `volatile` keyword also imply an `happens-before` relation concerning `a` and `b` fields? 
Or is it rather possible to end up with any thread seeing stale values (default values `0` in this case since `int`) due to a potential statements reordering during constructor?

In other word, should I declare `a` and `b` `final` or `volatile` to prevent any surprises with the JMM or is just indicating `volatile` on the instance's reference enough?

----------------**UPDATED POST - A GOOD ANSWER:**----------------------------

The following article confirms by its sample that in my case, `a` and `b` are protected from JMM optimisations that prevent a permanent ***happens-before*** relation.

http://jeremymanson.blogspot.fr/2008/11/what-volatile-means-in-java.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Declaring `instance` as `volatile` does not make its fields `volatile`, but if I understand your question correctly, then — yes, it's enough in your case.

Per [§17.4.5 of the spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5):

- a `volatile` write in one thread *happens-before* any subsequent `volatile` read in another thread.
- statements within the same thread have the *happens-before* relationship that you'd expect.
- *happens-before* relationships are transitive.

So, if a thread perceives `instance` as having been initialized, then the initialization of `instance` *happened-before* it, and the initialization of `instance`'s fields *happened-before* that, so the thread will perceive `instance`'s fields as having been initialized.

Comment: But reference is accessible by all threads even if the fields initialization aren't done yet (since not declared as final and can't rely on the constructor "freeze" for final variables) and so leading to a reference escape issue.

Comment: @Mik378: No; due to the transitivity of *happens-before* relationships, the reference won't be accessible to all threads until after the constructor has completed and (therefore) all fields have been initialized.

Comment: Please see the post just above (@atkretsch), I explained why.

Comment: @Mik378: Are you referring to http://jeremymanson.blogspot.fr/2008/07/immutability-in-java-part-2.html? Because it explicitly says, "this example would work if you made `lastConstructed` volatile". `final` has some of the same thread-safety benefits that `volatile` has; this does not mean that `volatile` lacks those benefits, but only that there's more than one way to get them.

Comment: Sorry for repeating along these posts, but to put in a nutshell, my question is: Knowing the issue that JMM and reordering could cause, does an instance's reference declared as being volatile ensure the COMPLETE initialization of the field's even these ones aren't declared volatile or final? Of course, I know that in the future of the process, `a` and `b` may be concerned by thread-safety violation; but I'm really talking about the initialization step => When the first other thread accesses the instance, does it ALWAYS see the good initial values indicated by the constructor?

Comment: After some additional reading (see my post at the bottom), my doubt disappeared :) Your answer is then relevant, thanks.

Comment: @ruakh: Being a non-native english speaker, I think I have misinterpreted your YES in second line of the answer. By YES, do you mean that by declaring [a and b final or volatile] will address the author's problem. Or do you mean just by making the object reference volatile in this case is enough?

Comment: @ShirgillFarhanAnsari: Just declaring `instance` as `volatile` guarantees that if a given thread sees the object via `instance`, then it will see the fully-initialized object.

Comment: You have yourself written - Declaring instance as volatile does not make its fields volatile. It clearly conflicts with the above comment you made.

Comment: @ShirgillFarhanAnsari: There is no conflict. Both statements are correct. Thanks for playing.

Comment: Oh I see that I didn't read via instance. I    deeply apologise for any inconvenience caused to you.

Answer (score 4):

**No** it's not enough to make it volatile. Thread safety depends on the usage though. E.g., this could still produce unexpected results if another thread is modifying the values.

*assuming `public` variables for simplicity*

```
volatile AmIThreadSafe instance = new AmIThreadSafe(1,2);
if (instance.x == 0) {
   // instance.x might have changed between checking and assigning
   instance.x = instance.x + 1;
}
```

`volatile` only applies to a variable (e.g., `x` and `y` are not automatically `volatile` just because `instance` is). This should be clear from [`JLS 8.3.1.4`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/classes.html#37715)

Comment: Ok :) I wonder this question just after looking for the real reason why volatile keyword could correct the reordering issue known with the "double-check locking" for singleton (even if I know it's a deprecated solution). So, I would add that this volatile keyword is not enough if the singleton instance owns some "normal" fields (non-final and non-volatile). Do you agree?

Comment: `volatile` guarantees that writes will be visible to all threads (preventing locally cached data), and has nothing to do with thread safety.

Comment: I do agree, my post's title was not relevant. I've just updated it.

Comment: You may read the last two posts of this page (at the very bottom) :http://jeremymanson.blogspot.fr/2008/07/immutability-in-java-part-2.html   Volatile or Final variables behave similarly facing to the JMM. So, I would deduce that a volatile instance's reference, when firstly read, get its deeper fields (`a` and `b`) up-to-date...

Answer (score 2):

The `volatile` in your case applies only to the reference of `AmlThreadSafe`. You still have to make the instance variables (`a` and `b`) `volatile` or access them in a `synchronized` block. Otherwise you can get stale data.

Comment: Thanks, you confirm my idea :)

Comment: hum... But this article says the contrary... :   http://jeremymanson.blogspot.fr/2008/05/double-checked-locking.html  reference volatile would encompass the complete initialization of deeper fields even these ones aren't declared as being volatile.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

```
thread 1                 thread 2

1 write(a)

2 write(instance)

                         3 read(instance)

                         4 read(a)
```

Since instance is volatile,  [2] happens-before [3].

Since happens-before is transitive, we have hb(1,2), hb(2,3), hb(3,4), therefore hb(1,4)

Comment: Do you confirm that making instance's reference volatile encompasses the complete initialization of deeper contained fields even theses ones aren't final or volatile (like my `AmIThreadSafe` class)?

Answer (score 0):

If `a` and `b` are only modified in the constructor, then in this case you should be fine because the object is created (and `a` and `b` set) BEFORE the reference is assigned to `instance`, and any other threads won't have locally-cached copies of the memory at those locations because it's a new object that the thread couldn't have seen before.  In other words, I don't believe it's possible that another thread will ever be able to see the "default" value of 0 for `a` and `b` because the constructor will run completely before the object's reference is assigned to `instance`.

However if `a` and `b` can be modified after the constructor, then the other answers here are correct - you need synchronization around them.

If you are going to assume that `a` and `b` won't be modified outside of the constructor, then there's no reason not to make them final anyway, just to be safe.

Comment: I disagree. Look at this article: http://jeremymanson.blogspot.fr/2008/07/immutability-in-java-part-2.html   Java Memory Model may lead to pitfalls...

Comment: Fair enough.  In that case, though, assuming your real-life constructor doesn't allow a reference to escape, then making `a` and `b` final should be sufficient.  Just didn't realize it was *necessary*.  I learned something new (and disconcerting) about Java today...

Comment: Exactly :) as soon as race condition between threads occurs (meaning accessing the same instance), if shared fields aren't final or volatile, the instance's reference could be returned and used even if the local cache is not sharing yet with other threads (through the main memory). => leading to stale data ...

Comment: Though there is this nugget in a comment on that post (made by the author): "Other threads are guaranteed to see the fields of b at least as up to date as they were when the constructor for a finished. If changes occur after that, the other threads may or may not see them."  To me, that seems to indicate that there isn't risk of any thread seeing a "default" value (as you feared in the original post) - just the usual risk that would come if those fields could be modified after the constructor and were visible to multiple threads.

Comment: Yes, but as long as the final keyword is used. In my post, I don't use any final variables.

Comment: Ah, yes, I missed the fact that in the example he was referring to, the reference to the class containing non-final fields was itself final even though the fields of the class were not.  Obviously that changes everything (and makes it irrelevant to your example...)

Answer (score 0):

Example :

```
class Something{
  private volatile static Something instance = null;
  private int x;
  private int y;
  private Something(){
    this.x = 1;
    this.y = 2;
  }
  public static Something getInstance() {
    if (instance == null) {
        synchronized (Something.class) {
            if (instance == null)
                instance = new Something();
            }
         }  
     }
   return instance; 
  }

}
```

**Explanation :**

---

Lets say we have the above Code:

Now lets assume instance is not volatile for some time:

*Thread#1* :
Comes in invoke getInstance method, Check for instance value{since null}, will go inside the IF condition, Access the Lock now again finds that instance == null, calls Something constructor. Now goes inside Constructor body.

As soon as Thread#1 goes inside Constructor body, Context Switch happens and now Thread #2 gets the turn to execute.

*Thread#2* :
Invokes get Instance, But suddenly finds that instance is not null?Why{Reason will discuss just after this}and hence assign partially constructed Object to reference and returns it.

Now Situation is like this : *Thread#1* Still needs to construct the Object Completely{needs to completely construct it} and *Thread#2* got reference for partially constructed Object, and if it uses it like say reference.x //will print "x" Default Value and not "1"

Why partially constructed Object reference is returned in case Of *Thread#2* ?
Reason is simple: **Statements Reordering**.
        The Steps are simple for Object creation and reference association :

1. Allocate Memory in Heap.
2. Execute the Body of Constructor which will initialize class members.
3. Once above Step is completed, Reference to newly created Object.

But Sometimes Compiler can execute these Instructions **out Of order**, which means :
It might happen something like this :

1. Allocate Memory in Heap.
2. Reference to newly created Object.
3. Execute the Body of Constructor which will initialize class members.

Once the above two Steps happens and if Context Switching Happens, then reference will point to Object which is not initialized or it might be the case that Inside Constructor Body Context Switch happens then in that case reference will refer to partially initialized Object.

If such scenario occurs then reference will neither be null nor complete and hence it will break our Singleton motivation.

Now How **Volatile** will save our Life from such embarrassments :
As we know Volatile work with two principles : 1)**Visibility** 2)**Happens Before Relationship**.
Now **Happens Before Relationship** comes into Picture here.

So reference is volatile Write, so all statements should happen before any Volatile write.Again If we look at our Object construction steps:

1. Allocate memory for Object
2. Initialize member variables{Constructor Body}
3. Assign Object reference to volatile variable instance.

Step 3 has **Volatile Variable write** and as per Happens before .. All statements write guaranteed to be made available to step 3. And since it is volatile therefore No reordering will happen between volatile and non volatile statements, which was not the case in Old Java Memory Model.
So before executing Step 3, Step 1 and Step 2 are guaranteed to be happened and made available to Step 3. {In which order Step 1 and step 2 occurs we don't bother about it.}

So from this Thread will see either Completely created Object or null